# I bought a box of used LEGO and found these 4 bags in it

Tags: set-identification

No pieces stand out. I see just one minifigure with a red body without anything indicating what it is. Any idea what set it belongs to?

[image]

Answer (score 39):

This is set [31025 Mountain Hut](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=31025-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) from the Creator theme. The Medium Blue window panes are in this set, and then the minifigure head you see in the top right bag identified this set.

[image]